# Promise.prototype.then() behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I have this promise:

```
var seasonalityArray;   

    ...

aService.gettingAnalysis(site, cohortKey)
            .then(function (result) {
                let date = moment();
                seasonalityArray = result.cooling.getSeasonMonths(date);
            })
            , function (error) {
                console.error('An error occurred', error);
            };


const totalAccounts = _.size(report.asModel().accountNumbers);

const warnings = _.compact(_.map(seasonalityArray, function (monthLabel) {

               ...

}));
```

...

```
   aService.gettingAnalysis = function (site, Key) {
        return Promise.all([
            aService.findingHeat(site, Key),
            aService.findingCool(site, Key)
        ]).spread(function (heating, cooling) {
            return { heating: heating, cooling: cooling };
        });
    };
```

Inside `seasonalityArray` variable, it must get an array of months (e.g. `['June','July','August']`)  which will be used afterwards.

The problem that I found while debugging each step is that after it goes in the line with `aService.gettingAnalysis` it doesn't enter in .`then()` and all the code after but it jumps to setting `totalAccounts` and afterwards it enters in warnings with `seasonalityArray` being `undefined`.

Is there a way to make it enter inside `then()` or at least to set that variable before it is using it as `undefined`?

Comment: you need to explain the nature of aService.gettingAnalysis(..) more - could you post the code up for that, or maybe add a JSFiddle ?

Comment: Also, the formatting of this code is incorrect - this would likely produce some strange errors. Furthermore, this isn't the way promises work. Promises are async as in synchronous code execution will still apply - there will be no blocking of code therefore the `seasonalityArray` will always be undefined.

Comment: umm.. could you update the question text ? it'll be much clearer that way. thanks

Comment: repeat this mantra ... *Promises do not make asynchronous code synchronous* ...

Answer (score 2):

```
aService.gettingAnalysis(site, cohortKey)
        .then(function (result) {
            let date = moment();
            seasonalityArray = result.cooling.getSeasonMonths(date);
            //now we can do the rest
            const totalAccounts = _.size(report.asModel().accountNumbers);

            const warnings = _.compact(_.map(seasonalityArray, function (monthLabel) {}));
        })
        , function (error) {
            console.error('An error occurred', error);
        };
```

Possible duplicate of *how to return from an asynchronous call*, so you may read a bit more about Promises.
A Promise is not meant to execute right now, but *somewhen*. So you cannot simply put code behind  it and expect it to execute *after* the Promise has finished. And you may have a look at *async* && *await* ...

Comment: now, somewhen or maybe never...

Answer (score 2):

If you need the data to be there when you use it you have to use it after your promise resolves.You can move the work you need to be done to a
function.

```
var seasonalityArray;

...

aService.gettingAnalysis(site, cohortKey)
    .then(function(result) {
        let date = moment();
        seasonalityArray = result.cooling.getSeasonMonths(date);
        doStuff();
    })

function doStuff() {
    const totalAccounts = _.size(report.asModel().accountNumbers);

    const warnings = _.compact(_.map(seasonalityArray, function(monthLabel) {
        ...
    }));

}
```

I'd do away with the "global" and chain promises instead.

```
aService.gettingAnalysis(site, cohortKey)
    .then(function(result) {
        let date = moment();
        seasonalityArray = result.cooling.getSeasonMonths(date);
        return seasonalityArray;
    }).then(doStuff)

function doStuff(seasonalityArray) {
    const totalAccounts = _.size(report.asModel().accountNumbers);

    const warnings = _.compact(_.map(seasonalityArray, function(monthLabel) {
        ...
    }));

}
```

`then` returns a `promise` where the data that get's resolved is what the `then` returns.